# How can I use the boost visitor concept with a class containing state variables?

Tags: c++, boost, visitor-pattern, boost-variant

I'm attempting to use boost::static_visitor to implement actions on a boost::variant type that affect the state of some variable. My approach was to contain all of the state variables in my command visitor class, but it seems this is not possible.

Here is my code example:

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>


struct TypeA
{
    int varA;
    int varB;
};

struct TypeB
{
   std::string varA;
   std::string varB;
};

typedef boost::variant<TypeA, TypeB> MyVariantType;

class MyCommandVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
//These are just examples, the actions only need to be able to touch
// internal variables.
void operator()(TypeA & t) const
{
   m_runningSum += t.varA;
   m_outStream << "TYPEA ACTION: " << t.varB << std::endl;
}

void operator(TypeB & t) const
{
   m_charCount += t.varA.size();
   m_outStream << t.varB <<  " ACTION " << t.varA << std::endl;
}

std::string emitWork(std::vector<MyVariantType> listOfVariants)
{
    m_outStream.clear();
    m_runningSum = 0;
    m_charCount = 0;
    BOOST_FOREACH(MyVariantType & v, listOfVariants)
    {
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
    }
    return m_outStream.str();
}

protected:
int m_runningSum;
int m_charCount;
std::stringstream outStream;
}; //End class MyCommandVisitor


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TypeA ta;
    ta.varA = 1;
    ta.varB = 2; 

    TypeB tb;
    tb.varA = "String1";
    tb.varB = "String2";
    std::vector<MyVariantType> listOfWork;
    listOfWork.push_back(ta);
    listOfWork.push_back(tb);
    MyCommandVisitor myCV;

    std::string result = myCV.emitWork(listOfWork);

    std::cout << "Result:\n" << result << std::endl << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I hope this snippet gets across the gist of what I'm trying to accomplish. It won't compile, however, giving the [paraphrased] error:

```
error: no operator "<<" matches these operands
   operand types are: const std::stringstream << const char [N]
m_outStream << "TYPE A ACTION: " << t.varB << std::endl;
             ^
```

I'm assuming this error is due to the const modifier that must be placed on the end of the operator() function prototype which makes the compiler believe that member variables cannot be modified by the function.

My question is thus:

**What is the proper way to accomplish the visitor pattern (using boost::variant) with variables that must maintain state between visits?**

Comment: Why do you say the `const` modifier **must** be put on `operator()`? `apply_visitor()` also has an overload taking a non-const `Visitor&`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There were a couple of typos, but I made a few mods and it works now. Essentially your static_visitor class is mutating itself on each visit, so the operator() methods can't be const.

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <boost/variant.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <iostream>


struct TypeA
{
    int varA;
    int varB;
};

struct TypeB
{
   std::string varA;
   std::string varB;
};

typedef boost::variant<TypeA, TypeB> MyVariantType;

class MyCommandVisitor : public boost::static_visitor<>
{
public:
//These are just examples, the actions only need to be able to touch
// internal variables.
void operator()(TypeA & t)
{
   m_runningSum += t.varA;
   m_outStream << "TYPEA ACTION: " << t.varB << std::endl;
}

void operator()(TypeB & t)
{
   m_charCount += t.varA.size();
   m_outStream << t.varB <<  " ACTION " << t.varA << std::endl;
}

std::string emitWork(std::vector<MyVariantType> listOfVariants)
{
    m_outStream.clear();
    m_runningSum = 0;
    m_charCount = 0;
    BOOST_FOREACH(MyVariantType & v, listOfVariants)
    {
        boost::apply_visitor(*this, v);
    }
    return m_outStream.str();
}

protected:
int m_runningSum;
int m_charCount;
std::stringstream m_outStream;
}; //End class MyCommandVisitor


int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    TypeA ta;
    ta.varA = 1;
    ta.varB = 2; 

    TypeB tb;
    tb.varA = "String1";
    tb.varB = "String2";
    std::vector<MyVariantType> listOfWork;
    listOfWork.push_back(ta);
    listOfWork.push_back(tb);
    MyCommandVisitor myCV;

    std::string result = myCV.emitWork(listOfWork);

    std::cout << "Result:\n" << result << std::endl << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

running on http://www.compileonline.com/compile_cpp11_online.php gives:

```
Compiling the source code....
$g++ -std=c++11 main.cpp -o demo -lm -pthread -lgmpxx -lgmp -lreadline 2>&1

Executing the program....
$demo 
Result:
TYPEA ACTION: 2
String2 ACTION String1
```

Comment: Thanks for the help! I was under the impression the const was required at the end of the operator() because all of the examples showed it, and when I tried to remove it for one operator (but not all), I got quite the list of compiler errors.

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to write a constructor for the visitor that initialises all those sums and counts to zero. At the moment they contain garbage.

Answer (score 3):

I'd personally favour making the functor const. Instead, I like to bind the functor arguments to references:

```
static std::string emitWork(std::vector<MyVariantType> const listOfVariants) {
    int sum = 0, charCount = 0;
    std::stringstream os;
    BOOST_FOREACH(MyVariantType const& v, listOfVariants) {
        boost::apply_visitor(
            boost::bind(MyCommandVisitor(), _1, boost::ref(os), boost::ref(sum), boost::ref(charCount)), 
            v);
    }
    return os.str();
}
```

Note that

- `emitWork` can now be static, reentrant etc.
- the `operator()` can now be `const`

The rest of the visitor would look like this:

```
struct MyCommandVisitor : boost::static_visitor<> {
    void operator()(TypeA const& t, std::stringstream& os, int& sum, int& /*charCount*/) const {
        sum += t.varA;
        os << "TYPEA ACTION: " << t.varB << std::endl;
    }

    void operator()(TypeB const& t, std::stringstream& os, int& /*sum*/, int& charCount) const {
        charCount += t.varA.size();
        os << t.varB << " ACTION " << t.varA << std::endl;
    }
};
```

See it **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/7053b78b2c895004)**